# How to fix "Json Parse Error: Unexpected EOF" error sent in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api

I'm developing a ReactNative App, and to create a new user, I'm creating a JSON with the information given by the user, and I send it to a PHP file which Parse the JSON received to store it in the database.
The problem is that my JSON doesn't send, and I have this magnificent Red Screen:

> "JSON Parse Error : Unexpected EOF"

If you have a solution for me, that would be wonderful.

Here is my code for the Fetch:

```
Insert_Data_Into_MySQL = () =>
{
    this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading : true }, () =>
    {
        fetch('http://MyPathToMyServerButDontWorryItsAnExample/NewUser.php',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: 
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(
            {
              product_name : this.state.Product_Name,
              product_number : this.state.Product_Number,
              product_details : this.state.Product_Details
            })

        })
        .then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJsonFromServer) =>
        {
            Alert.alert(responseJsonFromServer);
            this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading : false });
        }).catch((error) =>
        {
            console.error(error);
            this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading : false});
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Anyone got answer?